# Unwanted white space beneath ImageView in ViewPager android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I'm using ViewPager as image slider. I'm using **Android Studio**.  Everything works fine, I can slide between images. However beneath my images I have for some reason white space. I know that you can't call wrap_content on ViewPager and I've tried to put the fragment which contains the image slider into an Activity with another fragment below the image-slider-fragment, but between them is still some weird white space and within the white space I can also swipe to another image, which would of course cause only problems later on:

fragment_home.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="HomeFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="ImageSliderFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_image_slider"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="BottomFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_bottom"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

swipe_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_of_slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
<!-- adjustviewBounds prevents non-defined padding -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_of_swipe_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_image_slider.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="ImageSliderFragment"
android:id="@+id/image_slide_id">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager_of_image_slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<!--height="wrap_content/match_parent" both have the same result -->

</FrameLayout>
```

CustomSliderAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomSliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private int[] image_res = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,
        R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d};
private String[] image_names = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomSliderAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_res.length;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view == (RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view_of_slider);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_of_swipe_layout);
    imageView.setImageResource(image_res[position]);
    textView.setText(image_names[position]);
    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
}
}
```

ImageSliderFragment.class:

```
public class ImageSliderFragment extends Fragment {
ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSliderAdapter adapter;
View myView;
public static int imageHeight;


public ImageSliderFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(myView==null) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_slider, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) myView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_of_image_slider);
        adapter = new CustomSliderAdapter(getActivity());

        //With this I could set height of ViewPager manually
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = viewPager.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = imageHeight;
        viewPager.setLayoutParams(params);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        ((ViewGroup) myView.getParent()).removeView(myView);
    }

    return myView;
}

}
```

[How activity looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XsvJ.png)

I've also tried to change the height of my xml file with numbers (f.e.200dp), which works, but there are so many different device screens that at some point it would get at some point messed up

So again **my problem is: make ViewPager fit to Imageview**,because I can swipe between images also in the white space. 
Help is much appreciated!

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content" to android:layout_height="0dp" of fragments

Comment: in which layout @Pravin? by the way thanks for your help

Comment: fragment_home layout

Comment: it works for a couple of seconds(but image gets compressed), but then the other fragment (BottomFragment) takes up the whole activity :O @Pravin, the bottom fragment is sliding up in a weird animation till it takes up whole activity.

Comment: Your fragments have both layout_height="wrap_content" and layout_weight="2" in a vertical linear layout. Which one do you want? You cannot have both.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify. You must have both attributes if you want to use weighted height, but the layout_height attribute will be ignored if layout_weight is present. I think what you are looking for is just to have layout_height="wrap_content" so you should remove the weight

Comment: I've read that layout_weight="2" will take up 2/4 of screen. Therefore I wanted both fragments to equally share the activity, which means 1/2 top fragment and 1/2 bottom fragment. However I've tried this also without layout_weight and without LinearLayout, these variations did all not solve the problem :/ @MrSalmon

Comment: well if you want to have the view pager fill half the screen then use the weight, and set your ViewPager's layout_height to match_parent. I'd suggest doing some more reading on how android layouts work. Understanding how things work will be infinitely more valuable than just trying things until they work.

Comment: Without layout_weight only **fragment_image_slider** is displayed with the white space, image takes up about half the layout and the white space fills the rest, no sign of **BottomFragment** @MrSalmon

Comment: At this point I will just refer you to d.android.com to go learn more. You can find the lessons you need to achieve what you want.

Comment: I understand android layouts perfectly fine, but like I've said I tried to put **fragment_image_slider** into an activity with another fragment to get rid of the white space, which is unfortunately not the case. I just want to get rid of the white space which is below the imageView @MrSalmon **d.android.com** Really?

Answer (score 2):

You can  try like this on your imageview for   viewpager    image ....

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```